# MySQL Random Query Generator

Tags: mysql, testing, percona

I am running a RQG test and keep getting this message after running for a couple of minutes or so:

```
2015-09-17T11:11:17 [25859] runall.pl will exit with exit status STATUS_ENVIRONMENT_FAILURE (110)
```

I have tried to search online but cannot find anything regards the meaning of this message.

This is the test i am running leading to this messages. But other tests keep producing the same message FYI.

```
perl runall.pl --basedir=/var/lib/mysql --gendata=conf/examples/example.zz --grammar=conf/examples/example.yy --threads=1 --queries=100000 --duration=3600
```

I am running the test on percona 5.6 server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use --dsn with ip and port to check if it can be started successfully.

```
perl gentest.pl --dsn=dbi:mysql:host=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:port=NNNNN:user=username:password=pass:database=test --gendata=conf/examples/example.zz --grammar=conf/examples/example.yy --threads=1 --queries=100000 --duration=3600
```

- ip is the host ip address
- port is the port to mysql client

Comment: Will give it a try and let you know how it goes